# execute bash file daily ? (OS=UNIX)

Tags: backup, unix, bash, command-line-interface

i want to execute bash file daily at 12:30 for example to make backup to something how i can do it ?? and other one monthly ????
the operating system is Unix

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to use the [cron](http://linux.die.net/man/8/cron) facility to do this. In particular you will have to edit the [crontab](http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference) file and add a couple of entries.

To run a job daily at 12:30 you would create an entry in the crontab file like so

```
30 12 * * * /path/to/your/DailyBashScript
```

to run a job monthly for example on the 1st of the month at 20:45

```
45 20 1 * * /path/to/yourMonthlyBashScript
```

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [cron](http://www.google.com/search?q=cron+tutorial).